# How do I find out what is causing an alert sound

Tags: 20.04, sound

My computer keeps giving an alert sound similar to a new email that arrived in Thunderbird but when I look there isn't one. I don't know which program is alerting me or why.  System - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Firefox web browser, Thunderbird mail client, LibreOffice, and Gimp are my most frequently used programs. My question is how do I find out the cause and how do I stop it?

Solution - I have found the cause. Thunderbird Mail was giving an alert every time it checked for emails, whether it found one or not.

Comment: At least for me I need to check the browser.. it gets harder to more tabs you have open as `firefox` does show a visual alert when a tab is making noise; but it's harder to see with tens of tabs open...

Comment: im my Ubuntu 18.04 sometimes Thunderbird makes a fake new received mail alert without a visual notification, i understand that Thunderbird just remind me the unread mails inbox. when i mark all inbox as read the sound alert gone.